# Fullcalendar's fc-highlight not applied on day change in custom calendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar, highlight

I have a Fullcalendar scheduler view which runs from 8PM Day 1 to 8PM Day 2

When dragging an event onto the calender, the class .fc-highlight is only applied from Day1 8PM-11.59PM. When hovering the event over Day 2, the class .fc-highlight is not applied

These are my events

```
<div id='external-events'>
        <div class='fc-event'>
            My Awesome Event
        </div>
        <div class='fc-event'>
            Foo
        </div>
        <div class='fc-event'>
            Bar
        </div>
</div>
```

This is how I set the time from 8PM to 8PM

```
minTime: "20:00:00", // this makes the calendar start at 8PM
maxTime: "1.20:00:00", // this makes the calender end 24 hours later at 8PM ( (8PM => 20) + 24 = 44)
```

I've set up a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a1bm85ro/).

Try picking up an event and drag it to 11PM. The background is grey. Hovering on to the next day, the background disappears.

[image: Here .fc-highlight covers the complete hour]

[image: Here .fc-highlight is not applied]

I would like the class .fc-highlight to stay active

Comment: I think it's because you're using a day view but then mangling it by setting the maxTime higher than midnight. Probably somewhere in the code it runs up against a hard limit of midnight where it doesn't add that class to the field beyond that. I haven't studied the code but that's all I can assume. You might want to try using a [visibleRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/visibleRange) definition, possibly combined with a [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/custom-view-with-settings) if necessary, to display the time period you want. I suspect that might work better.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your reply. After some tries, it looks like the issue is raised by the `minTime` setting combined with the daycount. Check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jvddrift/qa4kgLr1/18/

Here you can see that on day 1 the background disappears after 11 pm, but reappears at 8pm the next day.

Setting dayCount to 2, makes the background appear after 12am, but it disappears again after the 2nd 12AM

I do not have a solution for this yet.

Comment: @ADyson `visibleRange` does only seem to accept `date`, no `time`.
Setting it from `2019-04-29T:20:00:00` to `2019-04-30T:20:00:00` makes the calendar start at '00:00' and run to 11:59:59PM

Comment: In your JS fiddle example you've a) used "validRange" instead of "visibleRange", b) not removed the "minTime" restriction which will stop any times being shown before 8pm on any day, c) not even tried to specify the time inside the range object, as far as I can see. Additionally the range object appears to specify seven days, not 24hrs. If this is your attempt, I don't think you've finished writing it? Try this version instead: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzuv5kog/

Comment: In fact actually, you haven't made it dynamic either, so the next/prev buttons don't do anything. It just stays on the same date forever. Try implementing a callback function as mentioned in the visibleRange documentation: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzuv5kog/1/

Comment: P.S. I rolled the above into a more formal answer - see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is because you're using a "day" view but then mangling it by setting the "maxTime" higher than midnight. Probably somewhere in the fullCalendar code it runs up against a hard limit of midnight where it doesn't add that class to the field beyond that. I haven't studied the code but that's all I can assume, based on the observed behaviour.

The correct way to define a custom time period like this in your view is to use [visibleRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/visibleRange), and optionally combine that with a [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/custom-view-with-settings) (especially if you want to use other views in your calendar as well).

Here's an example of a Visible Range definition which will do what you need. The timeline will always display from 8pm on the currently selected day to 8pm on the next day. You should not specify any other options such as dayCount or minTime/maxTime in conjunction with this, as they will distort the final display:

```
visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
  return {
   start: currentDate.clone().startOf("day").add('20', 'h'),
   end: currentDate.clone().startOf("day").add('1', 'd').add('20', 'h')
  }
}
```

Here's a full working demo using that range definition as part of a custom timeline view, based on the earlier fiddle you posted: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzuv5kog/1/

Comment: thanks for thinking with me! I'm aware that my fiddle was not cleaned up nicely, sorry bout that.

Your example works perfectly however I have one issue with it. The calender can only be used between certain days, e.g. coming monday till next sunday

That's why I added the validRange. But I understand this will break the working example?

Comment: Ok, well that wasn't technically what you asked about originally, but there's no reason you can't add a validRange alongside it. https://jsfiddle.net/dv5j0khf/1/